# How to display a sticky post inside a div?

Tags: sticky-post

I have a  and inside it I would like to add the contents of the first sticky post.

I went on codex.wordpress.org to find more about wp_query and saw this code that I could use to solve my problem:

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in'  => $sticky,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $sticky[0] ) {
    // insert here your stuff...
}
```

What I don't know is if this is what I am looking for and if yes, what do I need to add in the if statement in order for this code to display the first sticky post inside my div?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply follow the example from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$query = new WP_Query( 'p=' . $sticky[0] );
```

The variable `$sticky` will hold an array of IDs, and you access the first sticky post via `$sticky[0]`.

Then you need the [WordPress Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop):

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    echo '<div>';
    the_title();
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
```